# Move files of Dir1 which do not exist in Dir2 into a new Dir3

Tags: bash, diff

I have the following environment:

```
**DirA**
file1
file2
file3

**DirB**
file1
file2
file4
```

Desired output:

```
**DirC**
file4
```

I have seen solutions to similar problems with diff, sed, and xargs, but i cannot seem to get it running.

```
diff -rq DirA >DirB | sed -n "s/^Only in \(folderA\): \(.*\)/'\1\/\2'/p" | xargs cp -vt DirC
```

A problem is that i am working with absolute paths (as DirA and DirB are on different disks), and i dont know how to adjust the sed commando accordingly.
Any help is apreciated.

Comment: perhaps [edit] your question with what you did try and the resultant output.

Comment: i have edited the post with more details.

Comment: Does it have to be bash? zsh has a `:|` array subtraction operator that would allow you to generate set difference `dirB\dirA` easily

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would take a little different approach (assuming only files in dirA and dirB -- no subdirectories and also assuming files have no special characters in the names):

```
$ ls dir[ABC]
dirA:
file1  file2  file3

dirB:
file1  file2  file4

dirC:
$ ( cd dirA && for f in * ; do if [[ ! -f ../dirB/${f} ]] ; then echo mv -n -- "${f}" "../dirC/" ; fi ; done )
mv file3 ../dirC
```

Adjust the paths to dirA, dirB, dirC accordingly and if you are happy with the `mv` commands that are echoed run the command again without the echo.